# PHPMailer attachment can not be found - file cannot be found on file system

Tags: php, phpmailer

All i get every time is 'file not found on file system'

```
<?php 
    if($_POST[upload])
    {    
        require_once('incs/phpmailer/phpmailer.php');
        $upload = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $mail = new phpmailer;
        $mail->AddAddress("email@email.com", "Email");
        $mail->AddReplyTo("info@site.com", "Information");
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;    // set word wrap
        $mail->AddAttachment($upload);  // add attachment
        $mail->IsHTML(true);    // set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
        $mail->Body = "This is the message body";
        $mail->Send(); // send message
    }      
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You should check for `$_FILES['upload']['error']` instead / first. That will tell you if the file was successfully uploaded.

Comment: Check your upload folder permission and make it writable if not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$upload = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
```